# How to take the exponent of math/big.Float in Go?

Tags: go

I couldn't find anything in [the API](https://godoc.org/math/big). Converting the number to a `math/big.Int` and back is not an option because the fractional component is significant to my calculation.

---

I'll end up repeatedly multiplying if there's no API, but that's a dissatisfying solution (`math/big.Int.Exp` is just `O(log(n))`)  which might not be practical when I run into this problem again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use [MantExp()](https://godoc.org/math/big#Float.MantExp) to take the exponent of a `big.Float` for a particular base/mantissa. Note that the formula for calculating the exponent for a given mantissa is:

```
x == mant × 2**exp
```